# Apply function over values of two matrices fast

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function f(x, y) where x and y are any objects. Now suppose I have two matrices (list of lists) of the same dimensions A and B. What's the fastest way to compute the matrix C that looks like:

```
[f(a_11, b_11),...,f(a_n1, b_n1)]
[               .               ]
[               .               ]
[               .               ]
[f(a_1n, b_1n),...,f(a_nn, b_nn)]
```

where every entry of C at coordinate i,j is just f(a_ij, b_ij). I know I could iterate and do this, but I have quite a few matrixes to do this for and they are of decent size. Therefore i'm interested in fast ways to do this in python. Thanks for the help, feel free to edit the title if something better fits.

Comment: Take a look to NumPy!

Comment: a and b aren't numbers in my case, they are tuples. Will numpy still work??

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization — see [When to optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: It will work if they're all the same type.